# Im having trouble with using mutliple parts to an if/else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a pearson myprogramming lab exercise. Not exactly what the error message is referring to. I tried flipping the choice = B and choice = T sections and what occurred was the error message just then said that there was an issue with the choice = B else missing if.

```html
CTest.java:17: error: 'else' without 'if'
  else if(choice = T)
  ^

1 import java.util.Scanner;
2 
3 class CTest {
4  public static void main(String [] args) {
5   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
6   
7   int age = 0;
8   String choice = null;
9   
10 System.out.print("Enter your menu selection: ");
11   choice = stdin.nextString();
12   if(choice = S);
13   {
14    if(age <= 21)
15    System.out.println("Vegetable Juice");
16    else System.out.println("Cabernet"); 
17   }
18   else if(choice = T)
19   {
20    if(age <= 21) 
21    System.out.println("Cranberry Juice");
22    else System.out.println("Chardonnay"); 
23   }
24   else if(choice = B)
25   {
26    if(age <= 21)  
27    System.out.println("soda");
28    else System.out.println("IPA"); 
29   }
30   else
31   {
32    System.out.println("invalid menu selection"); 
33   }
34 
35   
36  }
37 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Line 12: if(choice = S);
```

You shouldn't have a semicolon at the end.

Also I think you want == instead of = in your IF statements.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your first `if`.

```
if(choice = S);
```

`==` is a test of equality, while `=` is assignment. Also, the semi-colon terminates the `if` body. You wanted

```
if(choice == S) // <-- like so
```

And the same with `T` and `B` like

```
else if(choice == T)
```

and then

```
else if(choice == B)
```

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a semi-colon after the first if statment

```
if (choice == S)
{
    //[...]
}
```